# Bounds for the falling factorial $n^{\underline{k}}$ that matches bounds for factorial when $n=k$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, factorial

I am looking for bounds (upper and lower) for the falling factorial $n^{\underline{k}} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ that are valid for all $n \geq k$ and either coencides with or is close to the robbins bounds:

$\sqrt{2 \pi} n^{n+\frac{1}{2}} e^{-n} e^{\frac{1}{12n+1}} < n! < \sqrt{2 \pi} n^{n+\frac{1}{2}} e^{-n} e^{\frac{1}{12n}}$

I've spent a long time searching, and all the bounds that I know either only work for $n > k$ or have a very weak bound when $n = k$. I have also tried to do this myself using the Robbins bounds to bound $n!$ and $(n-k)!$, but this is only valid when $n>k$

Thanks!

Comment: For $n=k$ you have the usual factorial and the Stirling approximation applies.  These bounds come from the same approach, but are more detailed than is usually quoted.

Comment: The context is an academic applied math paper. I have used one bound for $n > k$ (which is not useful for $n=k$), then for $n=k$ I use the robbins bound stated above. It is really ugly to treat the $n=k$ case separately, so I am asking if there is some bound that is good for the falling factorial ($n >k$) and the regular factorial $n=k$.